# What does the "|" character before a package name mean?

Tags: linux-mint, apt

Trying to understand why Aptitude was installed on Linux Mint XFCE, I noticed that the output of `apt-cache rdepends --installed aptitude` is the following.

```
aptitude
Reverse Depends:
  libapt-pkg6.0
 |apt
  apt
  aptitude-common
  aptitude-common
  aptitude-common
  libapt-pkg6.0
  apt
 |apt
  mintbackup
  mintsystem
```

What does the `|` character before *apt* mean? Since *apt* is already listed, I take it that `|apt` has a particular meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[What does the pipe | indicate in apt-cache rdepends?](https://askubuntu.com/q/406806) *almost* explains it all. Rephrasing it:

If `apt-cache rdepends y` returns a `|x` line, that means `x` depends on `y | z | ...` (the pipe means "logical OR"). An analogy: A son depends on a father or a mother, so if you do `apt-cache rdepends father`, it would list `|son`, because son can do without the father if he has his mother.

But why do both `apt` and `|apt` show up in that list? Let's investigate:

```
$ apt-cache show apt | grep 'aptitude'
Suggests: apt-doc, aptitude | synaptic | wajig, dpkg-dev (>= 1.17.2), gnupg | gnupg2 | gnupg1, powermgmt-base
Breaks: apt-transport-https (<< 1.5~alpha4~), apt-utils (<< 1.3~exp2~), aptitude (<< 0.8.10)
```

`apt-cache` is also listing "Breaks". This is documented in the manual:

```
--no-pre-depends, --no-depends, --no-recommends, --no-suggests, --no-conflicts, --no-breaks, --no-replaces, --no-enhances
    Per default the depends and rdepends print all dependencies. 
    This can be tweaked with these flags which will omit the specified dependency type.
```

So that

```
apt-cache rdepends --no-breaks aptitude
```

causes `apt` to disappear from the output, while `|apt` is still there.

PS: Since your output contains 2 occurrences of `|apt` and more 2 of `apt`, your `apt-cache show apt` should return 2 entries with `| aptitude` and 2 entries with `aptitude` (maybe on "Recommends" and "Replaces" beyond "Suggests" and "Breaks", for example).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had to use more `apt-cache rdepends --installed --no-breaks --no-recommends --no-suggests --no-conflicts --no-breaks --no-replaces --no-enhances aptitude` to get only *mintbackup* and *mintsystem* as modules that depends on Apt. I was expecting an output closer to the one `aptitude why aptitude` gives (and that the list was strictly a list of reversed dependencies).